# Shap values beeswarm plot of top predictors without "sum of others"

Tags: r, plot, shap

I want to produce a beeswarm plot of the top 15 predictors of my target as established by the shap values analysis. I'm using the R `shapviz` command for that:

`plot=sv_importance(shp, kind="beeswarm",  alpha=0.5, show_numbers=T, max_display=15)`

However, the command also plots the `Sum of x other` shap values in the graph. Do you please have any suggestions about how the get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always easier to answer if we have a reproducible example, but I'll create one for the purposes of this answer:

```r
library(shapviz)

set.seed(1)

X_train <- data.matrix(`colnames<-`(replicate(26, rnorm(100)), LETTERS))
dtrain <- xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label = rnorm(100))
fit <- xgboost::xgb.train(data = dtrain, nrounds = 50)
shp <- shapviz(fit, X_pred = X_train)
```

Now we have a shapviz object called `shp`, with 26 features, so this should be comparable to your situation.

If we plot with `sv_importance`, we get a ggplot object where we can see the second value is an undesired row called "Sum of 12 other"

```r
p <- sv_importance(shp, kind = "beeswarm", show_numbers = TRUE, max_display = 15) 

p
```

[image]

To get rid of this, we simply remove rows referring to this data point from the data in the plot object (it appears in two different data frames in the plot object, so we have to remove rows from 2 data frames)

```r
p$data <- p$data[!grepl("Sum of", p$data$feature),]
p$layers[[3]]$data <-  p$layers[[3]]$data[!grepl("Sum of", p$layers[[3]]$data$feature),]
```

Now when we draw `p` again, the offending row is removed:

```r
p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Allan, thx! Do you think we need an argument `hide_others = FALSE` to avoid ggplot hacking?

Comment: @MichaelM I can't see a way of achieving this without ggplot hacking as it stands, so perhaps adding this option would be useful. I always think ggplot wrappers have a difficult balance to strike between ease-of-use, customizability and avoiding parameter bloat. I don't think `sv_importance` has a lot of parameters for a ggplot wrapper function though, so IMHO it would be worth adding. Nice package btw.

Comment: Haha. It kinda has a lot of parameters already... but I might add it later.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this question, "shapviz" 0.4.1 now has received a new option `sv_importance(, show_other = FALSE)` to control this:

```r
library(shapviz)

set.seed(1)

X_train <- data.matrix(`colnames<-`(replicate(26, rnorm(100)), LETTERS))
dtrain <- xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label = rnorm(100))
fit <- xgboost::xgb.train(data = dtrain, nrounds = 50)
shp <- shapviz(fit, X_pred = X_train)

sv_importance(
  shp, kind = "bee", show_other = FALSE, max_display = 15, show_numbers = TRUE
)
```

[image]