# How to customize x-axis range with shapviz

Tags: r, plot, range, shap

I'm plotting the shap values of my variables using the `shapviz` package. Specifically, I'm plotting a beeswarm plot using the `sv_importance` command, and dependence plots for the most important variables using `sv_dependence`. However, to make the results of different models more easily comparable, I would like to customize the x-axis range to make it equal for every plot. Do you have any suggestions about how to customize the axis range for shapviz objects?  Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(shapviz)

set.seed(1)

X_train <- data.matrix(`colnames<-`(replicate(26, rnorm(100)), LETTERS))
dtrain <- xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label = rnorm(100))
fit <- xgboost::xgb.train(data = dtrain, nrounds = 50)
shp <- shapviz(fit, X_pred = X_train)

p <- sv_importance(shp, kind = "beeswarm", show_numbers = TRUE, max_display = 15) 

p

d <- sv_dependence(shp, v="I") 
d
```

From here, how can I make the x-axis range in the plot `p` equal to [-2.0, 2.0] instead of [-1.0, 0.5] (as it is by default)?

Comment: If [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74252435/shap-values-beeswarm-plot-of-top-predictors-without-sum-of-others/74256290#74256290) doesn't help, please post a reproducible example. Otherwise, it's impossible to give you any specific advice.

Comment: This should work I hope, sorry for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p` is a ggplot object, so you can add whatever scale you like. Just be aware that the "x" axis is actually the y axis, since `coord_flip` is used internally:

```r
library(ggplot2)

p + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-2, 2))
```

[image]